# My zoomed magnific modal images have no close button

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, popup, magnific-popup

I'm hoping to use Magnific Popup v1.1.0 to allow users to zoom on images on my webpage. My initial tests seem positive, but I note that there is no close box.

I have downloaded the Magnific Popup css and js, and put it in my current directory. It seems to all be working except no close widget ('x' in the upper right). It won't close on 'esc' or 'click', either.

Here's my code (note that I'm using Bootstrap 3.4 at present. My jquery is at 3.3.1):

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>ATmega8a Dice!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magnific-popup.css">
</head>
<body>
            <a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="dice_atmega8a_Pictures/completed kit.png" title="Caption. Can be aligned to any side and contain any HTML.">
                <img src="dice_atmega8a_Pictures/completed kit.png" width="75" height="75">
            </a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/usr/share/javascript/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
                type: 'image',
                closeOnContentClick: true,
                mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
                image: {
                        verticalFit: true
                }

        });

        $('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
                type: 'image',
                closeOnContentClick: true,
                image: {
                        verticalFit: false
                }
        });

        $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
                type: 'image',
                closeOnContentClick: true,
                closeBtnInside: true,
                fixedContentPos: true,
                mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
                image: {
                        verticalFit: true
                },
                zoom: {
                        enabled: true,
                        duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
                }
        });

});
    </script>
</body>```
````

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug in magnific pop up. In order to use button inside container you have to supply fixedContentPos: true; It may help you.

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        removalDelay: 100, // Delay in milliseconds before popup is removed
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-slide-bottom',`enter code here` // Class that is added to popup wrapper and background
        closeOnContentClick: false, 
        closeOnBgClick: false,
        showCloseBtn: true,
        closeBtnInside: true,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        alignTop: true,
//        settings: {cache:false, async:false},
        callbacks: {
            open: function () {   
            },
            beforeClose: function () {
                this.content.addClass('light-speed-out');
            },
            close: function () {
                this.content.removeClass('light-speed-out');
            }
        },
        midClick: true

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was a good clue, that I wasn't doing anything wrong. See my answer for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I figured it out. Compare

http://www.schwager.com/Pages/Products/test-jquery-2.2.4.html

with

http://www.schwager.com/Pages/Products/test-rh7.6-jquery.html

Click on the image in each one.

In the former, I use jquery that I downloaded myself from https://code.jquery.com/jquery/ . In the latter, I use the jquery that I installed from a package on Red Hat 7.6. The jquery version is 2.2.4, but the jquery.min.cs is a different size than the jquery.min.js v. 2.2.4 that I downloaded.

The test-jquery-2.2.4.html is working. I guess it's a bug in Red Hat's version of jquery?